# Quick sort with 2 pivots

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I have a question - when we are using quicksort with 2 pivots (let's say p1 and p2) - is that better than using quicksort with 1 pivot? What is the best and worst case of quicksort with 2 pivots?
I think p1 and p2 should divide the array into 3 equal parts (p1 = A[n/3] p2 = A[2n/3], while you look at it like the array is already sorted) but I don't know if I'm correct, thank you :)